# RestApi json results into a csv using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, rest

I'm trying to write the response returned from `RestApi` URL into a `csv` file for provided `port number`(Interactive mode) and selected users `users_list.txt` (Script mode). I have the below code to do the job.

```py
import json
import csv
import urllib.request
import subprocess

portvalue = input("Please enter an Port Number:\n")
portvalue = int(portvalue)
print(f'You entered {portvalue}')

tooluser='admin'
toolpassword='password'

user = open('users-list.txt')
for line in user:
   bash_com = 'curl --user {tooluser}:{toolpassword} http://198.98.99.12:46567/{portvalue}/protects/{user}  \
         | jq --arg a_port {portvalue} --arg a_userid {user} 'map(.+{"userid":{user}}+{"port":{portvalue}})'' as url:

subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bash_com])
print(line)
myfile.close()

# with urllib.request.urlopen("curl --user admin:password http://198.98.99.12:46567/{port}/protects/{user} | jq") as url:

data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

fname = "output.csv"

with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
 csv_file.writerow(["depotFile","host","isgroup","line","perm","user","port","userid"])
    for item in data["raw_data"]:
        csv_file.writerow([item['depotFile'],item['host'],item['isgroup'],item['line'],item['perm'],item['user'],item['port'],item['userid']])
```

Curl with URL to get data for single user - `curl --user admin:password http://198.98.99.12:46567/2324/protects/sanchez.ricardo | jq`

`users_list.txt` consists of users in below format.

```
sanchez.ricardo
varun.sharma
daniel.vel
```

One of the `json` output format as follows,

```
[
  {
    "depotFile": "//LIB/Include/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "19",
    "perm": "open",
    "user": "5G",
    "port": "2324",
    "userid": "sanchez.ricardo"
   },
....
......
.........
]
```

**Expected output csv file:-**

```
Sno     depotFile       host  isgroup  line   perm    user    port  userid
1   //LIB/Include/...   *              19     open    5G      2324  sanchez.ricardo
2   //LIB/...           *              19     write   6G      2324  varun.sharma
3   //AND/RIO/...       *              20     write   AND     2324  daniel.vel
```

I'm unable to process the `RestApi URl` in above code. Please help me to achieve this in python. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you still need help with this, can you add a userlist example file with two users, and the actual url you hit to get the csv for the two users?

Comment: @ Brian Z, yes still i am looking for a help. i have added `userlist` file and actual `url` information in the question. please have a look and help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use requests to grab stuff as it is so easy now, it has improved drastically over its beginnings. It is so much easier than pyCurl now that I am in the process of refactoring code to use it as I make improvements to the code over time.

Here is a really cool website to convert a curl command to requests code:

https://curl.trillworks.com/

so:

```
curl --user admin:password http://198.98.99.12:46567/2324/protects/sanchez.ricardo
```

is:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://198.98.99.12:46567/2324/protects/sanchez.ricardo', auth=('admin', 'password'))
```

Now it looks to me like your loop isn't going to work. It loops and assigns the stuff to bash but then doesnt do anything until the loop is done. Probably you accidentally unindented it though. At any rate, here is a loop that should work, using the suggestion of f-strings as suggested in another answer.

I am not completely sure of what you get back from the api, seems like you need to make multiple requests to get json for each, so I wrote it that way. I am sure you need to tweak some stuff but this should get you closer.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
user_csv = '''sanchez.ricardo
varun.sharma
daniel.vel'''
# I cannot tell where you get the ports from, so I will put a list here to show the code working
# and you can fill it differently, maybe from the csv?? not sure
ports = [2324, 2324, 2324]
users = user_csv.split('\n')
fname = "output.csv"
with open(fname, "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file,lineterminator='\n')
    csv_file.writerow(["depotFile", "host", "isgroup", "line", "perm", "user", "port", "userid"])
    for user, port in zip(users, ports):
        print(f'from csv and other method here is the user and port: {user}, {port}')
        url = f'http://198.98.99.12:46567/{port}/protects/{user}'
        print(f'grab data from rest api: {url}')
        # cannot tell if there is one user:password for the REST API, this code assumes so
        response = requests.get(url, auth=('admin', 'password'))
        # assuming response returns json like this:
        # response = '''[
        #   {
        #     "depotFile": "//LIB/Include/...",
        #     "host": "*",
        #     "isgroup": "",
        #     "line": "19",
        #     "perm": "open",
        #     "user": "5G",
        #     "port": "2324",
        #     "userid": "sanchez.ricardo"
        #    }]'''
        data = json.loads(response)
        for item in list(data):
            csv_file.writerow(item.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, f-string is probably what you're looking for. Consider this:-

```
user='sanchez.ricardo'
port=2324

url = f'http://198.98.99.12:46567/{port}/protects/{user}'
```

Comment: 'port' is run time input variable and 'user' I need to pass from text file. Such case how do I deal in python?

Comment: Use input() to get information directly from the user (interactive) or pass command-line arguments to get the port value. Open a file and read its contents to get the user details

Comment: Did you notice what happened when you tried to run that code? urlopen, unsurprisingly, expects a URL

Comment: I need to pass only `URL` not the `Curl along with URL`?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I can't access the host site, I can't write and test any code for you

Answer (score 0):

The second snippet you have only covers the part

```sh
curl --user $USERID:$PASSWORD http://198.98.99.12:46567/$PORT/protects/$u \
          jq --arg a_port $PORT --arg a_userid .....
```

---

From what I undrtstand you want both funcionalities

1. from user input - *interactive mode*.
2. from file - *script mode*.

Many things can be done but what I would do is use [Argeparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html) and maybe have a switch param `-ulf|--users-list-file` to pass a file or simply no param for interactive mode.

And have the port be passed via environment variable, and read that using [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ), aswell as a `-p|--port` as an optional param

A quick'n dirty way is to use [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) to read passed arguments and write your conditions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have been going through your code, you can simply use [request](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and use pandas to store data in CSV. This will make easy output.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
json_string = '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"None" }'

a_json = json.loads(json_string)
print(a_json)

dataframe = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a_json)
```